# Flask werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I've tried several different flask apps and get the following error every time.

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
>
> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad
> Request: KeyError: 'name'

I can't figure out why.  It must be something with my setup because the same thing is happening in different applications.  I set up a very simple model with minimal code to demonstrate.  If I remove the `name` key I get the same error with the `number1` key.  And I can't find anything on what this error even means.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///flow.sqlite3'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from routes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, request
from app import app, db
from models import Info

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    data = Info(request.form['name'], request.form['number1'], request.form['number2'])
    db.session.add(data)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

models.py

```
from app import db

class Info(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    number1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    number2 = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, number1, number2):
        self.name = name
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id='basic' action="index.html" method="post">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      <label for="number1">Number 1:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number1">
      <label for="number2">Number 2:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number2">
      <button id='btn_submit' type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't do separate GET and POST handling. A GET will not have form variables.

Answer (score 5):

When your page is first loaded, there is no `request.form` dictionary, which is why you get the key error. You need to write an if statement to check if the form was submitted or if the page is being loaded the first time.

```
from flask import redirect, url_for

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
      data = Info(request.form['name'], request.form['number1'], request.form['number2'])
      db.session.add(data)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
      return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: That worked.  I used a "try/except" rather than an if statement, but not catching that was the problem.  Very much appreciated, Burhan.