# Flask BadRequest with a simple form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

**Hey there !**

having some problems using input from a simple form
getting werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
KeyError: 'first'

HTML

```
  <body>
    <form id="inform" method="POST">
      User name:<input name="first" type=text>
      message:<input name="second" type=text>
      <input id="sendBtn" type="button" value="send">
    </form>
    <pre id="chatbox">Loading...</pre>
  </body>
```

python

```
today=date.today()
app=Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
def first():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/<room>",methods=['GET'])
def second(room):
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/chat/<room>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def third(room):
    if request.method == "GET":
        pass
    elif request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form["first"]
        massage = request.form["second"]
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        f=open(f"chat room {room}", "w")
        f.write(f"room number {room}\ndate and time {dt_string}\nusername {name} massage {massage}")
        f.close()
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True)
```

getting this error :

```
10.0.0.4 - - [18/May/2021 11:03:02] "POST /api/chat/5454 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700053/flask-werkzeug-exceptions-badrequestkeyerror

Answer (score 0):

Your function `third` is causing this error. Since you are allowing both the `GET` and `POST` methods, you have to handle them separately. A `GET` request doesn't contain any form variables, which is exactly why it throws the error.

So, You can use conditionals to perform different actions for different methods:

```
@app.route("/chat/<room>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def third(room):
    if request.method == "GET":
        # do something
    elif request.method == "POST":
        # do something else

    return render_template('index.html')
```

You can put all the stuff of your current `third` function in the `elif` block of this code.

Comment: i edited the code with your suggestions,getting a new error

Comment: What error are you getting? Please remember you have to put something in those commented lines

Comment: 10.0.0.4 - - [18/May/2021 11:03:02] "POST /api/chat/5454 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: You are making `POST` request to `/api/chat/5454` but the URL for the view is `/chat/5454`.

Comment: hmm i see what you mean.where do i fix it ?